# Как вывести изображение в зависимости от высоты?

Tags: jquery

Всем добрый день!

Код что-то никак не заработает... Надо при вводе числа от х до у, чтоб выводило изображение, а оно - никак.

Вот код

```
if(( $('#scale').css('height')>='10%') && ( $('#scale').css('height')<'25%')){
    $("#dn_meter").css('backgroundImage', 'url(../images/donate10.jpg)');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var s = $('#scale'), h = s.height()/s.parent().height()*100;
if(h >= 10 && h <= 25)
{
    ...
}
```

Вот только ума не приложу, куда здесь прикрутить x и y.

Comment: не работает :'(

Comment: А можете показать ваш код уже в полном варианте на сайте? (сегодня утром посмотрю). И, кстати, выводите промежуточные значения куда-нибудь - это может здорово помочь.